# How do you show horizontally the submenu in WordPress using the nav walker?

Tags: html, css, menu

I've added a nav walker in my wordpress theme. It looks like this:

Functions.php

```
* Register Custom Navigation Walker
 */
function register_navwalker(){
    require_once get_template_directory() . '/class-wp-bootstrap-navwalker.php';
}
add_action( 'after_setup_theme', 'register_navwalker' );


/*Navigation Menus*/
function register_my_menu() {
  register_nav_menu('header-menu',__( 'Header Menu' ));
}
add_action( 'init', 'register_my_menu' );
/*End*/
```

and then header.php

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg">
   <div class="container"><a href="home" class="navbar-brand home"><img src=<?php echo get_template_directory_uri() . '/img/logo_pezzini_big.png';?> alt="Obaju logo" class="d-none d-md-inline-block"><img src=<?php echo get_template_directory_uri() . '/img/logo_pezzini_small.png';?> alt="Obaju logo" class="d-inline-block d-md-none"><span class="sr-only">Obaju - go to homepage</span></a>
     <div class="navbar-buttons">
       <button type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navigation" class="btn btn-outline-secondary navbar-toggler"><span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span><i class="fa fa-align-justify"></i></button>
       <button type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#search" class="btn btn-outline-secondary navbar-toggler"><span class="sr-only">Toggle search</span><i class="fa fa-search"></i></button><a href="basket.html" class="btn btn-outline-secondary navbar-toggler"><i class="fa fa-shopping-cart"></i></a>

      <header>
        <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg">
            <!-- Brand and toggle button -->
            <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Navbar</a>
            <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarSupportedContent" aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
                <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
            </button>

            <!-- End -->
            <!-- Your website Links -->
            <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarSupportedContent">
                <?php
                     wp_nav_menu( array(
                     'menu'              => 'primary',
                     'theme_location'    => 'header-menu',
                     'depth'             => 4,
                     'container'         => 'div',
                     'container_class'   => '',
                     'container_id'      => '',
                     'menu_class'        => 'navbar-nav mr-auto',
                     'fallback_cb'       => 'wp_bootstrap_navwalker::fallback',
                     'walker'            => new wp_bootstrap_navwalker())
                     );
                ?>

            </div>
            <!-- End -->
        </nav>
</div>
</header>
```

It works pretty well, but the sub-menu is vertical and I'd like to have it horizontal. Here how it looks:
[image]
but it should show like:

```
SOCKS | UNDERWEAR | TSHIRTS | etc......
```

This is the HTML generated by the navwalker and CSS:

```css
.dropdown-sub a:after {
    display: inline-block;
    width: 0;
    height: 0;
    margin-left: .255em;
    vertical-align: .255em;
    content: none;
    border-top: .3em solid;
    border-right: .3em solid transparent;
    border-bottom: 0;
    border-left: .3em solid transparent;

}
.dropdown-toggle::after {
  display: none;
}

.menu-large {
  position: static !important;
}

.menu-large .megamenu {
  padding: 20px;
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 1140px;
  left: 50%;
  -webkit-transform: translateX(-50%);
  transform: translateX(-50%);
  margin-top: -1px;
}

.menu-large a.nav-link {
  padding: 7px !important;
  padding-left: 0 !important;

}
.navbar {
  border-bottom: 1px solid #e6e6e6;
  background-color: #fff;

}
/*BOX INTORNO INTERO MENU*/
.navbar .navbar-nav > .nav-item > .nav-link {
  text-transform: uppercase;
  letter-spacing: 0.1em;
  font-weight: 700;
  padding: 30px 15px !important;
  color: #555;

}


@media (max-width: 991.98px) {
  .navbar .navbar-nav > .nav-item > .nav-link {
    padding: 10px 15px !important;
display: inline;
  }
}
/*BOX INTORNO SINGOLI ITEMS PRINCIPALI QUANDO HOVER*/
.navbar .navbar-nav > .nav-item > .nav-link.active, .navbar .navbar-nav > .nav-item > .nav-link:hover, .navbar .navbar-nav > .nav-item > .nav-link:focus {
  background: #379392;

}

@media (max-width: 991.98px) {
  .navbar .dropdown-menu {
    position: relative !important;
    border: none;
    list-style-type: none;

  }
}

@media (min-width: 992px) {
  .navbar .dropdown:hover .dropdown-menu {
    display: block;
    list-style-type: none;
  }
}

.navbar .megamenu {
  padding: 30px !important;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0 6px 12px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.175);
  box-shadow: 0 6px 12px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.175);



}

@media (max-width: 991.98px) {
  .navbar .megamenu {
    padding: 15px !important;
    -webkit-box-shadow: none;
    box-shadow: none;

  }
}

.navbar .menu-large h5 {
  font-size: 1.125rem;
  font-weight: 400;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  letter-spacing: 0.1em;
  padding-bottom: 10px;
  border-bottom: dotted 1px #555;
  text-transform: uppercase;

}

@media (max-width: 767.98px) {
  .navbar .menu-large h5 {
    font-size: 0.9rem;
  }
}

.navbar .menu-large ul {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;

}

.navbar .menu-large ul .nav-item {
  list-style-type: none;
  border-bottom: solid 1px #eee;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  letter-spacing: 0.1em;
  padding: 4px 0;


}

.navbar .menu-large ul .nav-item a {
  color: #999;
  font-size: 0.738rem;
  display: block;
  padding: 0 !important;


}

.navbar .menu-large ul .nav-item a:hover {
  color: #379392 !important;
  text-decoration: none;

}

.navbar .menu-large .banner {
  margin-bottom: 10px;

}

.navbar #basket-overview {
  padding: 0;
}

.navbar .navbar-btn {
  color: #fff;
  margin-right: 10px;

}

#search {
  background: #fff;
}

#search .container {
  text-align: right;
}

#search form {
  max-width: 500px;
  padding: 20px 0;
}

#search .navbar-form {
  float: right;
  width: 500px;
}

.breadcrumb {
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0 1px 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
  box-shadow: 0 1px 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
  background: #fff;
  border-radius: 0;
  padding: 0.5rem 1rem;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-9aIt2nRpC12Uk9gS9baDl411NQApFmC26EwAOH8WgZl5MYYxFfc+NcPb1dKGj7Sk" crossorigin="anonymous">

<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg">
   <div class="container"><a href="home" class="navbar-brand home"><img src="http://calze.test/wp-content/themes/calzepezzini%20-%20Copy/img/logo_pezzini_big.png" alt="Obaju logo" class="d-none d-md-inline-block"><img src="http://calze.test/wp-content/themes/calzepezzini%20-%20Copy/img/logo_pezzini_small.png" alt="Obaju logo" class="d-inline-block d-md-none"><span class="sr-only">Obaju - go to homepage</span></a>
     <div class="navbar-buttons">
       <button type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navigation" class="btn btn-outline-secondary navbar-toggler"><span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span><i class="fa fa-align-justify"></i></button>
       <button type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#search" class="btn btn-outline-secondary navbar-toggler"><span class="sr-only">Toggle search</span><i class="fa fa-search"></i></button><a href="basket.html" class="btn btn-outline-secondary navbar-toggler"><i class="fa fa-shopping-cart"></i></a>

      <header>
        <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg">
            <!-- Brand and toggle button -->
            <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Navbar</a>
            <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarSupportedContent" aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
                <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
            </button>

            <!-- End -->
            <!-- Your website Links -->
            <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarSupportedContent">
                <div class="menu-nuovo-container"><ul id="menu-nuovo" class="navbar-nav mr-auto" itemscope="" itemtype="http://www.schema.org/SiteNavigationElement"><li id="menu-item-25" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-home current-menu-item page_item page-item-16 current_page_item active menu-item-25 nav-item"><a itemprop="url" href="http://calze.test/" class="nav-link" aria-current="page"><span itemprop="name">Home</span></a></li>
<li id="menu-item-66" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-has-children dropdown menu-item-66 nav-item"><a href="#" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false" class="dropdown-toggle nav-link" id="menu-item-dropdown-66"><span itemprop="name">Men</span></a>
<ul class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="menu-item-dropdown-66">
    <li id="menu-item-45" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-45 nav-item"><a itemprop="url" href="http://calze.test/socks/" class="dropdown-item"><span itemprop="name">socks</span></a></li>
    <li id="menu-item-69" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-69 nav-item"><a itemprop="url" href="http://calze.test/underwear/" class="dropdown-item"><span itemprop="name">Underwear</span></a></li>
    <li id="menu-item-46" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-46 nav-item"><a itemprop="url" href="http://calze.test/tshirts/" class="dropdown-item"><span itemprop="name">Tshirts</span></a></li>
    <li id="menu-item-70" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-70 nav-item"><a itemprop="url" href="http://calze.test/accessories/" class="dropdown-item"><span itemprop="name">Accessories</span></a></li>
</ul>
</li>
<li id="menu-item-67" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-has-children dropdown menu-item-67 nav-item"><a href="#" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false" class="dropdown-toggle nav-link" id="menu-item-dropdown-67"><span itemprop="name">Ladies</span></a>
<ul class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="menu-item-dropdown-67">
    <li id="menu-item-71" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-71 nav-item"><a itemprop="url" href="http://calze.test/tights/" class="dropdown-item"><span itemprop="name">Tights</span></a></li>
    <li id="menu-item-73" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-73 nav-item"><a itemprop="url" href="http://calze.test/short/" class="dropdown-item"><span itemprop="name">Short</span></a></li>
    <li id="menu-item-72" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-72 nav-item"><a itemprop="url" href="http://calze.test/underwear/" class="dropdown-item"><span itemprop="name">Underwear</span></a></li>
</ul>
</li>
<li id="menu-item-68" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-68 nav-item"><a itemprop="url" href="http://calze.test/kids/" class="nav-link"><span itemprop="name">Kids</span></a></li>
<li id="menu-item-26" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-26 nav-item"><a itemprop="url" href="http://calze.test/about-us/" class="nav-link"><span itemprop="name">About us</span></a></li>
<li id="menu-item-27" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-has-children dropdown menu-item-27 nav-item"><a href="#" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false" class="dropdown-toggle nav-link" id="menu-item-dropdown-27"><span itemprop="name">Contact us</span></a>
<ul class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="menu-item-dropdown-27">
    <li id="menu-item-41" class="dropdown-sub menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-has-children dropdown menu-item-41 nav-item"><a href="#" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false" class="dropdown-toggle nav-link" id="menu-item-dropdown-41"><span itemprop="name">boxes</span></a>
    <ul class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="menu-item-dropdown-41">
        <li id="menu-item-42" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-42 nav-item"><a itemprop="url" href="http://calze.test/item1/" class="dropdown-item"><span itemprop="name">item1</span></a></li>
    </ul>
</li>
</ul>
</li>
</ul></div>
            </div>
            <!-- End -->
        </nav>
</header>
</div>

    
 <!--search and cart-->

       <div class="navbar-buttons d-flex justify-content-end">
         <!-- /.nav-collapse-->
         <div id="search-not-mobile" class="navbar-collapse collapse"></div><a data-toggle="collapse" href="#search" class="btn navbar-btn btn-primary d-none d-lg-inline-block"><span class="sr-only">Toggle search</span><i class="fa fa-search"></i></a>
         <div id="basket-overview" class="navbar-collapse collapse d-none d-lg-block"><a href="basket.html" class="btn btn-primary navbar-btn"><i class="fa fa-shopping-cart"></i><span>3 items in cart</span></a></div>
       </div>
     </div>
   
 </nav>
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. The display of the menu depends on the HTML and CSS rather than the walker code. Please edit your question to include the HTML that is generated by walker, and the CSS being applied to it in a [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example), so we can see what you are using and be able to help.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I'll do that in a while

Comment: html and css posted

Comment: I've added your code to a snippet, but the submenu is not showing. Something must be missing ( do you use JS to make the submenu appear maybe?). Take a look at getting the snippet to work and we'll see then how to turn it into a horizontal menu. Also - how do you want the horizontal menu to behave when it doesn't fit across the screen? Should it only be horizontal above a specific breakpoint?